# Can you write sql commands using a .bat file?

Tags: sql, sqlite, command-line, batch-file

I'm designing a process to create a list of fuzzy duplicates for my colleagues. I have automated most of the process and have used a .bat file to open sqlite. However, I can now find no other way to read the code other than to manually type:

```
     .read file_name.sql
```

Into command prompt. Is there a way I could type open and read the file from notepad with the commands prewritten, like a .bat file. For example:

```
    cd sqlite -- enter directory with sqlite3 inside of it. DOS command
    sqlite3 --to open the sqlite3 application DOS command
    .read file_name.sql  -- SQLite command
```

Thanks in advance, sorry if the question is trivial.

Comment: what does file - file_name.sql has ? Stored procs or SQL queries?

Comment: look for SQLCMD. that might help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give a command as parameter to the `sqlite3` tool:

```
sqlite3 mydatabasefile ".read file_name.sql"
```

Comment: In simpler terms, the explanation is that your SQL commands need to be enclosed by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on what you're looking to do with the [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) tool. It allows SQL to be run from the command line.